# GPO Enforcement

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, preferences

Newbie Jr SysAdmin here-

I'm writing some GPOs and would like to have some new preferences applied, but allow the user to change them after the initial deployment.  For example, I would like all the taskbar notification icons to display by default, but allow the user to change it so they have the option to select which ones to display, and stay that way.  I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 and deploying to Windows 7 PCs and laptops.

This is my first posting here as my previous job didn't give much administrative authority, so I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to ensure this happens is to use a runonce script. The setting is under Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Scripts/Startup. The GPO will execute a script of your craft on startup (login in this case) that will toggle all the options you desire. The trick to ensure that it only runs once is to drop a specific file that the script checks for before execution. Shamelessly scraped from this thread here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/126392-run-gpo-startup-script-once

Comment: Thank you!  I was headed in that direction, but wasn't sure if there was a GPO switch for it.  Learning something new everyday!!